# Use and display data from an API Flutter

Tags: xml, api, flutter, dart

I want to use data collected from this API (https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml) and use only one field, the <raw_text> of LFBL, I just want this field to be displayed in a Text widget, I can't manage to get this XML file and use only this field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package for parsing xml and find the tag and key
https://pub.dev/packages/xml

Comment: The thing is that I have no idea how to use this package with a website

Comment: you can send get request with this url and get content of response and pass it to the package and use find method

Comment: I tried this but it's not returning anything
`Future getMetar() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/current/metars.cache.xml');
    final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(url);
    final response = await request.close();
    print(response);
  }`